# GitHub link to large file diff

Tags: github, hyperlink, version-control, diff

I sometimes want to direct people to a diff on GitHub of a specific file. As an example:

https://github.com/jmd-dk/concept/commit/d6506f34b5bbf4d3565853878e24ab184f2b4bae#diff-4404040641087472e1742ef90deea885cc74425f96129ef9035fa959e3d8ef01

where the first hash is for the commit and the second is for a specific file, here `concept/species.py`. If the diff is large it's not rendered by default, and so one in addition needs to click the "Load diff" button. This extra step feels like a burden, as all I ever wanted was to see that specific file (changes to other files are present on the page as well, though ideally I wouldn't want that).

How can I construct a link pointing directly to the diff of a specific file on GitHub (as the example above) but with the diff already loaded without having to also click a button?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this.  That's because large diffs can take a long time to render, and if you could force it to load immediately in the foreground instead of in the background and there were multiple large diffs, the page would probably end up timing out and not loading at all.  GitHub has a timeout for rendering web pages, after which you just get a 500 error.

The goal of this approach is to make many more diffs viewable in the web interface than would otherwise be possible, and therefore improve the user experience.  Otherwise, many large diffs would just not work at all.